# Definite Integral. Perfomance problem

Tags: performance-tuning, numerical-integration

I have a notebook in Mathematica 4. I'm trying to convert it to use in Mathematica 9. One of the problem is the long computation of definite integral.
In Mathematica 4 the result of the following code
[image: code]

is ~18.4 and ~0.66 seconds, but the same code in Mathematica 4 gives me 0.266 and 0.031 !

Why?

upd. The code itself:

```
B[i_,j_]:=Integrate[(x-i)^i x^j,{x,-5,5}];
Timing[Sum[B[i,1],1,10];]
```

The real program is much more complex. This is just the small part of it.

Comment: Are you sure the delay is needed? I would use the undelayed assignment = and no :=

Comment: Please, provide the actual code rather than an image.

Comment: @coolwater the delay is certainly needed for the NIntegrate because anything except the integration variable should be numerical. It might not be necessary for the symbolical integration.

Answer (score 1):

One can calculate this integral analytically

```
Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, {x, -5, 5}, Assumptions -> {(i | j) ∈ Integers, j > 0}]
```

> ```
> ConditionalExpression[(1/(1 + j))
>  5^(1 + j) (-i)^i (Hypergeometric2F1[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, 5/i] + 
>  Hypergeometric2F1[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, -(5/i)] (Cos[j π] + I Sin[j π])), i < -5]
> ```

*Mathematica* returns the result for `i < -5` but it also correct for positive `i`.

Now you can define the function

```
b[i_, j_] := 1/(1 + j) 5^(1 + j) (-i)^i (Hypergeometric2F1[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, 5/i] + 
     Hypergeometric2F1[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, -(5/i)] (Cos[j π] + I Sin[j π]));
```

It is ~1000 times faster:

```
Sum[B[i, 1], {i, 1, 20}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {1.224481, -28464057995788622073916233379750/693}
> ```

```
Sum[b[i, 1], {i, 1, 20}] // AbsoluteTiming
```

> ```
> {0.001921, -28464057995788622073916233379750/693}
> ```

Comment: What version of _Mathematica_ are you using? I get a different result with V9.0.1.

Comment: @m_goldberg Also V9.0.1, on Linux. What is your result?

Comment: `Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, {x, -5, 5}, 
 Assumptions -> {(i | j) \[Element] Integers, j > 0}]` gives `ConditionalExpression[
 5^(1 + j) (-i)^
  i Gamma[1 + 
    j] (E^(I j \[Pi])
      Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, -(5/i)] + 
    Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[-i, 1 + j, 2 + j, 5/i]), i < -5]`. This is on OS X.

Comment: @m_goldberg It is equivalent answer since by definition `Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[a,b,c,z]` is `Hypergeometric2F1[a,b,c,z]/Gamma[c]`. However it is strange that the form of the answer is different in different OSs.

Comment: Even more interesting is that `Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, {x, -5, 5}, Assumptions -> {(i | j) \[Element] Integers, j > 0, i > 0}]` gives `ConditionalExpression[-((8 5^(6+j) (15+(-1)^j (7+2 j) (135+2 j (7+j) (17+j (7+j)))))/((1+j) (2+j) (3+j) (4+j) (5+j) (6+j))),i==5]`, which is also "equivalent", but for only one value of `i`.

Comment: @m_goldberg I have the same trouble so I use only `j > 0` :)

Comment: On my machine it takes longer to evaluate the first general (analytical) integral used to define `b` than it takes to evaluate `Sum[B[i, 1], 1, 10]`.  The sum of `b[i, j]` is only 1000 times faster if you have to evaluate it many times.  It is faster if you evaluate the sum even just twice, so it is an improvement.

Comment: Note you can just use the antiderivative `Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, x]`, which is faster.  You have to simplify it: `Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, x] /. Times[coeff_, h_Hypergeometric2F1] :> h Simplify[coeff, i \[Element] Integers && x > i]` -- boy, I hate how reluctant *M* is to simplify integer powers!  The assumption `x > i` is not true, but it produces valid results.

Comment: Thank you all for your performance tweaks, but I still don't get it. Why Mathematica 4 perform calculating much faster? Is there any significant difference between realisation of Integrate function in those versions of Mathematica? I'm not so good in Mathematica language and those assumptions tells me nothing, so i just used NIntegrate[..., AccuracyGoal->6].

Answer (score 1):

This is just the working out of the full details of the approach suggested by Michael E2 in his comment on ybeltukov's answer.

```
b[i_, j_] := 
 Evaluate @ 
   With[{
     f = 
       ((Integrate[(x - i)^i x^j, x] /. 
         Times[coeff_, hyper_Hypergeometric2F1] :> 
           Simplify[coeff, i ∈ Integers && x > i] hyper) /. 
             x :> #) &
     }, 
     f[5] - f[-5]]
Timing[Sum[b[i, 1], {i, 100}] // N]
```

> ```
> {0.020519, -5.40851*10^202}
> ```